# How to ask the hair stylist to cut off your hairs less or more on some parts of your head

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-request

How would you ask the hair stylist to cut your hairs some more or some less on some parts of your head? Do the following sentences work:

> - Cut less hair off this area.
> - Cut more hair off this area.

If they don't sound natural, then please let me know how can I ask them such a thing?

Comment: For hair cuts and talking about hair, the singular is used.

Answer (score 3):

You can always say

- *Please trim the left side.*
- *Make it shorter on the right side.*
- *Leave the center as it is, while making the sides shorter.*

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are correct; however, it is more common to say "leave this area longer than the rest" and "make this area shorter than the rest" in everyday usage.